# Bulk flow interviews not interacting with one another

Tags: visual-workflow, bulkification, transaction

My goal is to run a flow in bulk and not create duplicates. First thing that happens is I lookup colCustomObject. The first interview loops through colCustomObject, determines that a new record needs to be created. Define the sobject variable and add it to colCustomObject and colCustomObjectForCreation. I expect the second interview (which would otherwise create a duplicate) to see the new value in colCustomObject, but it never does. Can collections be modified and the modifications visible in different interviews in the same transaction?

The weirdest part is I have something very similar working perfectly in a different org, but cannot seem to duplicate it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flows that you have running in parallel will not see changes made by one another to their flow variables, including collection variables. Those values are private to the Flow interview. I'm not seeing a way that your parallel flows could be running inside the same transaction context, either.

The new records you're creating are only visible once they've been persisted to the database through a Record Create or other DML element. At that point, other processes of all types will be able to query them.

Note that this is true of both Apex and Flow. No transaction can see what's going on in any other transaction. If you're creating a lot of duplicates in parallel imports, you'll need to either fix your input process to dedupe up front, or clean up on the back end.

However, each running import process (again, either Apex or Flow) can see everything that's already been committed as a result of other transactions. The issue that you're observing should only be the case when duplicate records are being processed in parallel transactions simultaneously. Otherwise, a properly bulkified query for duplicate records should locate them.

Comment: So if I am going to do a bulk import and want to avoid duplicates, I need to use apex. Because there I can query the things that are about to be created and cut off any duplicates.

Comment: It's not about Apex vs. Flow. No transaction can see what's going on in any other transaction. If you're creating a lot of duplicates in parallel imports, either fix your input process to dedupe up front, or clean up on the back end.

Comment: Thanks, that helps me understand a good bit. So the opportunities being imported themselves are not duplicates, but they trigger the creation of a record that links between the account and a custom object. So if two opportunities are related to the same account they will often create duplicate links. Any suggestions on what to do then?

Comment: Sequence them by parent Account Id before you initiate the import and code your Flow so that it only creates one link per Account/Custom pair in the transaction. That will dramatically reduce the volume of duplicates, at minimum. Consider defining an External Id = AccountId + CustomId and performing an upsert. But be aware that you cannot fully block duplication without a trigger on the link object and exception handling in the flow.